# Get the type of a input from an HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to retrieve the type of my HTML form input in Javascript for further use. I'm not speaking about the *type* attribute of HTML input but the type of variable you get with *typeof* JS operator.

I'm using the code below to test it :

```
<form oninput="test();" name="myform">
<input name="anumber" value="100">
<input name="aboolean" value="true">  
</form>
<div id="message"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function test(){
    anumber = document.myform.anumber.value;
    aboolean = document.myform.aboolean.value;
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = anumber + " " + typeof(anumber) + " | " + aboolean + " " + typeof(aboolean)
   }
</script>
```

In my dream, this displays : "100 number | true boolean" and not "100 string | true string". Can you help me to define the custom function to make it ?

Thank for your help !
Nicolas

Comment: http://dreamscometrue.uk.com/

Comment: `input type="text"` = text. `input type='checkbox'` = boolean. See: http://jsfiddle.net/ZUJzF/

Comment: Values from input elements are stored as strings. You'd have to write a custom function that determines your type based on the value of the string.

Comment: Thank you @AnthonyGrist, it's exactly what I would like find here. I reformulate my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `value` property of an input element is always stored as a string, so `typeof` is always going to return "string". You'd need to write a custom function that looks at the contents of that string and determines the correct type accordingly. Something like this may suffice, though I've likely missed one or two cases:

```
function getInputType(value) {
    if(value === "")
        return "";
    else if(value === "true" || value === "false")
        return "boolean";
    else if(!Number.isNaN(Number(value)))
        return "number";
    else
        return typeof value;
}
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Nj62g/)