# How to get typeof entered value?

Tags: javascript, typeof

**UPDATE:** [SOLVED] Thanks everyone for answering me, I have tried two method and it is really work!
Here are jsbin for them:

[This one was inspired by Secret's answer](http://jsbin.com/lekegikeni/1/edit?output)

[This one is from Alexander's O Mara's answer](http://jsbin.com/huvihudita/1/edit?output)

I'm trying to check if the entered value is number or not.
I'm using `typeof` to check it. If entered value is number, `alert('number');`. But if entered value is string, `alert(’string');`.

The problem is, it always `alert(’string');` although the entered value is number.

What's wrong? How can I solve it?

Here is my code:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="inputText" id="inputText">
<input type="button" onclick="alertType()" value="alertType">
<script>
 function alertType()
 {
  var someStr = document.getElementById("inputText").value;
  var someStrType = typeof someStr;
  alert(someStrType);
 }
</script>
```

Comment: See [Validate decimal numbers in JavaScript - IsNumeric()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-decimal-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric)

Comment: Define "number" Do you mean an integer? A decimal? Can it be negative?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the type of a input from an HTML form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19513041/get-the-type-of-a-input-from-an-html-form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply cast the string to a number using [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number), and use [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) to check if it was successfully cast to a number. `Number` will return `NaN` if it fails to cast to a number, which `isNaN` can detect.

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="inputText" id="inputText">
<input type="button" onclick="alertType()" value="alertType">
<script>
 function alertType()
 {
  var someStr = document.getElementById("inputText").value;
  var someNum = Number(someStr);
  if (isNaN(someNum)) {
    alert('not a number');
  }
  else {
    alert('a number');
  }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! Use `Number()` as a magical spell to cast it to number really work!

Answer (score 1):

Problem here is your data source is textbox which gives value as string. You need to parse it to number.

Answer (score 1):

```
var my_numberA = 3;     //  This is typeof number
var my_numberB = '3';   //  This is typeof string
```

So depending on how you write it: a 3 is a number where '3' is a string

The trick is to do the following:

Any string multiplied by 1 will convert the string to a number.
However, multiplying a string that can not be represented by a number will return an error.
So you need to compensate for that possibility with a try{}catch(err){} that converts the string to a number if possible

```
function convertToNumber(input){
    try{var output = 1*input}catch(error){var output = input}
    return output
}

var my_numberA = 3;     //  This is typeof number
var my_numberB = '3';   //  This is typeof string

console.log( typeof my_numberA ) // Will show 'number'
console.log( typeof my_numberB ) // Will show 'string'

console.log( typeof convertToNumber(my_numberA) ) // Will show 'number'
console.log( typeof convertToNumber(my_numberB) ) // Will show 'number'
```

I prefer this in some cases rather than the `Number()` function because it returns the same passed object instead of returning NaN.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, when you get the inputText value from your dom, it **is** a string. For example, `"12"` is a string, vs. a `12`

What you can do is to check if *it is not a number*:

```
function alertType()
 {
  var someStr = document.getElementById("inputText").value;
  if(isNaN(someStr)){
     //it's not a number!
  } else  { 
     //it's a number!
  }
 }
```

Comment: Be careful though, isNaN returns `false` for things like `0xdeadbeef`, an empty string, etc. Depending on what you want, a regex is often a better choice...

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
$('#clickMe').click(function () {
    var inputVal = $("#inputText").val();
    var value = Number(inputVal);

    if (isNaN(value)) {
        alert('not a number');
    } else {
        alert('a number');
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mky9vxdy/1/